# android, block special character in searchview

Tags: android, filter, special-characters, searchview

I'm a newbie on programing specially with android.
I use a SearchView in my app but I don't know how block special character.
I have seen topics about EditText but nothing about SearchView and I need help.

I use SearchView in App bar with this xml for menu :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

and this Activity code :

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);

}

 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_option_menu, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
}
```

So I waiting your answers, thanks.

Comment: done, it's tutorial from Google.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect when a char is entered:

```
//In onCreate
EditText et;//initialize
et.addTextChangedListener(tw);
```

outside onCreate:

```
private TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //If the text contains a "bad" char, (char that isn't equal to A-Z/a-z or 0-9, remove it from the edittext
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```

(the edittext should be declared as a class variable)

Suggestion as to detection:

```
//s is the char sequence

String string = s.toString();
boolean found = false;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    String ch = s.charAt(i) + "";//Convert to check with regex
    if(!Pattern.compile("[A-Z|a-z|0-9]").matcher(ch).find()){
        found = true;
    }else{
        sb.append(ch);
    }

}
if(found){
    editText.setText(sb.toString());//only apply the text if a special char is found
}
```

My interpretation of special char was non-numeric and non-A-Z. This can be modified  to match any char you count as special. If there is a few chars you want to disallow, it is better to check for those chars instead of checking if it contains all the others.

Comment: I'm not sure it will work with SearchView, no setText() for SearchView

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue with '>' being converted to '|>'. This is how I fixed it with Kotlin:

```
override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
    Log.w(TAG, "new text $newText")
    if (newText != null && newText.contains("|>")) {
        val text = newText?.replace("|>", ">")
        search.setQuery(text, false)
    } else {
          // do something
    }
    return false
}
```